# How to create calculated column / Property in the User Profiles with Visual Studio or Manually?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, web-part, user-profile, user-profile-property

I have to create one **calculated column / Property** in the **User Profiles** with custom / Visual Studio or Manually.
Is it possible and How?
I know that, we can create the Property but I don't know how to create calculated property/column.

Comment: No one had tried this?

Comment: Apparently you can't have calculated properties in User Information List... You also can't develop a workflow for User Information List as it's an external database (not really SharePoint)... What do you need this for? There's always a workaround :)